# How to fix "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable" in requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, mailgun

My goal for this code is to send an email using Mailgun. I'm using calling it from Flask using the `requests` library:

**contact.py**

```
def index():
  data = request.form.to_dict()
  send_email(data)
  return "Success!"
```

**send_email()**

```
def send_email(data: dict):
  data = format_data(data)

  return requests.post(
    API_URL,
    auth={ "api": API_KEY },
    data=data,
  )
```

I know it has something to do with the `send_email()` function but I'm currently stuck at how to solve it.

---

**EDIT**: Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "contact.py", line 9, in index
    send_email(data)
  File "/home/david-hermes/Desktop/Projects/frontend/web/single-page-resume/send_email.py", line 44, in send_email
    data=data,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 309, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 540, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2019 21:01:28] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Right, so `auth={ "api": API_KEY }` is the dictionary. And that's because the [`auth` keyword argument doesn't take a dictionary](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `api` argument incorrectly. You want to pass in the username and password combination *as a tuple*:

```
auth=("api", API_KEY),
```

The Mailgun API indeed [requires you to pass in the API key as a Basic Auth password](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#authentication), but to send a Basic Authentication header using the `auth` keyword argument you either pass in a [`HTTPBasicAuth()` instance or a tuple](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/#basic-authentication):

> Making requests with HTTP Basic Auth is very simple:
>
> ```
> >>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
> >>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
> <Response [200]>
> ```
>
> In fact, HTTP Basic Auth is so common that Requests provides a handy shorthand for using it:
>
> ```
> >>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
> <Response [200]>
> ```
>
> Providing the credentials in a tuple like this is exactly the same as the `HTTPBasicAuth` example above.